# Sharing ruby code for Sinatra::Base & Sinatra::Application classes

Tags: ruby, inheritance, rubygems, sinatra, reusability

I am quite new with Sinatra framework and I am trying to do a gem compatible with Sinatra::Base & Sinatra::Application based apps. I have this code in my gem and it is working fine in both apps:

health_check.rb

```
class App1 < Sinatra::Base
  get '/health/liveness' do
    halt 204
  end
end

class App2 < Sinatra::Application
  get '/health/liveness' do
    halt 204
  end
end
```

But I the code is repeated and I would like to have something like this, but it does not work:

health_check.rb

```
module HealthHelper
  get '/health/liveness' do
    halt 204
  end
end

class App1 < Sinatra::Base
  include HealthHelper
end

class App2 < Sinatra::Application
  include HealthHelper
end
```

When I try to init any app with the gem included I get this error

```
/lib/health_check.rb:3:in `<module:HealthHelper>': undefined method `get' for HealthHelper:Module (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  gets
               gem
```

Any idea to make it cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than simply using `include`, you can write a [Sinatra extension](http://sinatrarb.com/extensions.html) that defines the routes.

It might look something like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module HealthHelper
  def self.registered(app)
    app.get '/health/liveness' do
      halt 204
    end
  end
end

# This line is so it will work in classic Sinatra apps.
Sinatra.register(HealthHelper)
```

Then in your actual apps, you use `register` instead of `include`:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'health_helper'

class App1 < Sinatra::Base
  register HealthHelper
end
```

Now the routes will be available in `App1`. Note that you probably don’t want to be extending `Sinatra::Application`, but rather `Sinatra::Base`.

Comment: I have been trying a lot of ways with inheritance blocks, procs...  and I have reached a simpler solution but your post in more instructive. I will give yours as the better

Answer (score 1):

After lots of tries I reach a very simple solution:

health_check.rb

```
class Sinatra::Base
  get '/health/liveness' do
    halt 204
  end
end
```

Sinatra::Application is a subclass of Sinatra:Base so I included the code directly in the Sinatra:Base class definition.